# Can't install H5PY library on Windows 10 - Python

Tags: python, installation, pip, h5py

I need to install a lb named **h5py** but when i try to install it in Powershell with those commands it doesn't work :

```
pip.exe install h5py

pip install libhdf5-dev
```

It's my second time working on windows and i don't understand how to fix this error:

```
PS C:\Users\UIC01685\Desktop\h5py-master> pip.exe install h5py
Collecting h5py
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03483CD0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/h5py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03483E30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/h5py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03483F10>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/h5py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034DF030>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/h5py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034DF130>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/h5py/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for h5py

PS C:\Users\UIC01685\Desktop\h5py-master> pip install libhdf5-dev
Collecting libhdf5-dev
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03D48CF0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/libhdf5-dev/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03D48E50>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/libhdf5-dev/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03D48F30>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/libhdf5-dev/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DA5050>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/libhdf5-dev/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DA5150>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/libhdf5-dev/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libhdf5-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libhdf5-dev
```

I also try to install by downloading the source but when i run **python.exe .\setup.py install** i have this error:

```
PS C:\Users\UIC01685\Desktop\h5py-master> python.exe .\setup.py install
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pkgconfig/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pkgconfig' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for pkgconfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\setup.py", line 155, in <module>
    cmdclass = CMDCLASS,
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 128, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\AMESim\R19SL1\Amesim\sys\python\win64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 667, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pkgconfig')
```

I'm working in a big company with some restriction so i checked if i have a proxy and run this command line in my cmd:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

It said that i'm in in **direct access (no proxy server)**

Any idea ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is clearly a connection issue. Since you are working in a company this question should be adressed to your IT department. We cannot know what configurations you might have to make to get your connection working.

Comment: @FlyingTeller raah i wasn't sure about that ok then i'll ask to my IT department.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setup.py` is trying to download some requirements listed in `setup.py`, in this case `pkgconfig`. As there seeems to be a connection issue to pypi using https, it fails. Try asking your IT department (as you are working in a company they should know if you need to configure something special) or download pkgconfig from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pkgconfig/) manually.